# C#.NET ChildWindow Position + Maximize

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main application form, I've set the IsMdiContainer property to TRUE

I have a panel in the main application form on the top but when I open the ChildForm it opens behind the panel. How do I set location relative to the bottom of the panel + maximize the window?

Comment: The eternal MDI question.   You must set the Dock property on the panel so it is docked to one side of the parent and shrinks the dark-gray MDI client window.

Comment: When I set the forms window state to 'FormWindowState.Maximized'

I still have the same issue. It's not filling up within the parent area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans said in comments, Set the `Dock` property of `Panel` to `Top` for example. And add your Mdi Childs this way:

**Example:**

```
private void MdiTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Codes for test only
    var f = new Form();
    f.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
    f.MdiParent = this;
    f.Show();
}
```

**Note:**

You can access to `MdiClient` control this way:

```
var mdiClient = this.Controls.OfType<System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient>().First();
```

Then you can do anything with it if you need. It is a Control like other controls.

**Normal State:**

[image]

**Maximized State:**

[image]